# Why is my PageView.builder only calling the itembuilder for index 0 and not the full range?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I am creating a scrollable newsfeed. I call my newsfeedtile using the following code which works fine:

```
`ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: 1, // Replace with actual number of rows
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return NewsFeedTile(
                    title: "This is a sample title", 
                    timestamp: "3h ago", 
                    text: "Sample text", 
                    imageUrls: [

'https://loveincorporated.blob.core.windows.net/contentimages/gallery/cfca340a-9c53-4713-b4e0-b17d6648b8ac-shutterstock_1164740191.jpg', 
'https://pixlr.com/images/index/remove-bg.webp',
'https://loveincorporated.blob.core.windows.net/contentimages/gallery/cfca340a-9c53-4713-b4e0-b17d6648b8ac-shutterstock_1164740191.jpg'
                      ], 
                    upVotes: "1", 
                    downVotes: "22", 
                    commentCount: "10");
                }`
```

However the code below my NewsFeedTile has a PageViewBuilder as follows:

```
`PageView.builder(
                        itemCount: widget.imageUrls.length,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        pageSnapping: true,
                        controller: pageController,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return _buildPage(
                              context, index, calculatedMaxHeight);
                        },
                      ),`
```

For some reason - if i print index and widget.imageUrls.length, index is always 0 even though widget.imageUrls.length is 3. Therefore it isnt building all the pages needed?

Full code for the newsfeedtile below:

```html
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class NewsFeedTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String timestamp;
  final String text;
  final List<String> imageUrls;
  final String upVotes;
  final String downVotes;
  final String commentCount;

  const NewsFeedTile({super.key, 
    required this.title,
    required this.timestamp,
    required this.text,
    required this.imageUrls,
    required this.upVotes,
    required this.downVotes,
    required this.commentCount,
  });

  @override
  _NewsFeedTileState createState() => _NewsFeedTileState();
}

class _NewsFeedTileState extends State<NewsFeedTile> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  late PageController pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Initialize pageController and currentIndex here
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: currentIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.imageUrls.length);
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
            spreadRadius: 5,
            blurRadius: 5,
            offset: const Offset(0, 2),
          ),
        ],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      ),
      child: StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: Text(
                  widget.title,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  maxLines: 2,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                child: Text(
                  widget.timestamp,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: Text(
                  widget.text,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              FutureBuilder<double>(
                future: calculateMaxHeight(),
                builder:
                    (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<double> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          strokeWidth: 3,
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    double maxHeight = 100;
                    double calculatedMaxHeight = snapshot.data ?? maxHeight;
                    return Stack(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: calculatedMaxHeight,
                          child: PageView.builder(
                            itemCount: widget.imageUrls.length,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            pageSnapping: true,
                            controller: pageController,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return _buildPage(
                                  context, index, calculatedMaxHeight);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          left: 0,
                          top: calculatedMaxHeight / 2 - 20,
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_back,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1)
                                    .remainder(widget.imageUrls.length);
                              });

                              pageController.animateToPage(
                                currentIndex,
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          right: 0,
                          top: calculatedMaxHeight / 2 - 20,
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon:
                                const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1)
                                    .remainder(widget.imageUrls.length);
                              });

                              pageController.animateToPage(
                                currentIndex,
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: 0,
                          left: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                            child: Text(
                              '${currentIndex + 1}/${widget.imageUrls.length}',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 16,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Handle up arrow button press
                      },
                    ),
                    Text(widget.upVotes),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Handle down arrow button press
                      },
                    ),
                    Text(widget.downVotes),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.chat_bubble),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Handle speech bubble button press
                      },
                    ),
                    Text(widget.commentCount),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Handle share button press
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      child: Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        children: [
                          for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                            Positioned(
                              right: i * 15.0,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 40,
                                height: 40,
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                ),
                                child: Image.network(
                                    'https://panoraapp.com/assets/images/tiny_images/aljazeera.png'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          Positioned(
                            right: 45,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 40,
                              height: 40,
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                              ),
                              child: const Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  '+2',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPage(
      BuildContext context, int index, double calculatedMaxHeight) {
    print("Building page for index: $index");
    Image i = Image.network(
      widget.imageUrls[index],
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      height: calculatedMaxHeight,
    );
    return i;
  }

  Future<double> calculateMaxHeight() async {
    double maxHeight = 0;
    double containerWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    await Future.forEach<String>(widget.imageUrls, (imageUrl) async {
      Image image = Image.network(imageUrl);
      Completer<void> completer = Completer<void>();

      image.image.resolve(const ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
        ImageStreamListener(
          (ImageInfo info, bool _) {
            double aspectRatio =
                info.image.width.toDouble() / info.image.height.toDouble();
            double imageHeight = containerWidth / aspectRatio;
            if (imageHeight > maxHeight) {
              maxHeight = imageHeight;
            }
            completer.complete();
          },
        ),
      );

      await completer.future;
    });

    return maxHeight;
  }
}
```